# Problem with setting up a tabularx table

Tags: tabularx

I am trying to set up a tabularx table with very long item descriptions in first column

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lccc}\toprule
    Item & MW & SD & span\\\midrule
    This is a very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  long item description. & $2.58$ & $0.90$ & $1-4$  \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

At the moment, it compiles badly because LaTeX allows first column to extend to a lenght of the whole item description. What can I do to get a better result in which I have e.g. 5 lines text, but an acceptable broadness of the column?

Comment: It should compile very badly, i.e. not at all,  because `\toprule` is unknown. Please add `\usepackage{booktabs}` to your MWE also

Comment: Use columntype `X` for the first column: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xccc}`

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Additional question: how can I vertically center the values in my other colums (1-lined) if the item description goes along several lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use columntype `X` for the first column:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xccc}
```

The `X` is a column of the type `p`. If you want to vertically center the values in the other columns you have to redefine the `\tabularxcolumnn` to

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xccc}\toprule
    Item & MW & SD & span\\\midrule
    This is a very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  long item description. & $2.58$ & $0.90$ & $1-4$  \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```